# Adding thoughtbot's open_id_authentication to thoughtbot's clearance

Tags: ruby-on-rails, openid

I am working on an application that is currently using thoughtbot's clearance as its authentication piece. I want to add openID to this application and know that thoughtbot has an open_id_authentication plugin. Does anyone know how easy it is to go about doing this or if there is a tutorial or anything somewhere?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "open_id_authentication" plugin is not originally Thoughtbot's, it's probably just their fork of the main one. That plugin provides some useful controller methods, but doesn't integrate with Clearance out-of-the-box. You'll have to study how both work and write additional code in your app that inherits from Clearance controllers and mixes in OpenID authentication logic.

Comment: yeah i figured that out shortly after posting the question thanks